# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable, when I try to fit my model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import layers
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

#some variables
act_function = 'tanh'
input_x = np.ones((1000, 2, 4, 5, 1))#arbitrary array as an example
target = np.ones((1000, 2, 64, 100, 1))

decoder = Sequential()
decoder.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(2, 4, 5, 1)))
decoder.add(layers.Conv3D(8, (1, 3, 3), activation=act_function, padding='same', name = 'h8'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling3D((1, 2, 1), name = 'h9'))#8 5

decoder.add(layers.Conv3D(16, (1, 3, 3), activation=act_function, padding='same', name = 'h10'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling3D((1, 2, 5), name = 'h11'))#16, 25

decoder.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (1, 3, 3), activation=act_function, padding='same', name = 'h12'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling3D((1, 2, 2), name = 'h13'))#32, 50
decoder.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (1, 3, 3), activation=act_function, padding = 'same',name = 'h14'))
decoder.add(layers.UpSampling3D((1, 2, 2), name = 'h15'))#64 100
decoder.add(layers.Conv3D(1, (1, 3, 3), activation=act_function, padding='same', name = 'out'))
decoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'mse')

decoder.fit(input_x, target, epochs=10)
```

**Error**:

```
  In [163]: decoder.fit(input_x, target)
  Epoch 1/10
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [163] in <cell line: 1>
    model.fit(input_x, target)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/keras_environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1193 in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/keras_environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:885 in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

  File ~/anaconda3/envs/keras_environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:917 in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable

  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Editted 1:**
In comments I was asked to explain how I define my dataset. Input dataset is `numpy.ndarray`, all elements in this array are *floats*(can be positive and negative). Target dataset is also `numpy.ndarray` consisting of *floats* (can be positive and negative).

```
input_x.shape
>>(1000, 2, 4, 5, 1)

target.shape
>>(1000, 2, 64, 100, 1)
```

Where **1000** is number of samples, each sample is complex signal, **2** is for real and imaginary part of each sample, **64** and **100** is matrix(64x100), and **1** is value(matrix entry). Dimension **2** might be confusing, so here is an example:

```
target[:, 0, :, :, :]# contains real part of complex signal
target[:, 1, :, :, :]# contains imaginary part of complex signal
```

**Editted 2:**
As mentioned in comments. I tried to minimize my question and make it Reproducible.

Comment: What's the shape of `input` and `target`.

Comment: @Djinn its written above  {input_shape(10, 2, 4, 5, 1), target_shape(10, 2, 64, 100, 1), dtype = float}

Comment: Can you update the question with how you defined your dataset?

Comment: The only thing I can see is you're missing the `epochs` argument in `.fit()`. It needs to be an integer and since you're not passing anything, it's current value might be `None`.

Comment: @Djinn i tried with `decoder.fit(input, target, epochs = 2)`, same error ;(

Comment: Does the model actually complete an epoch? Also by how the dataset was defined, I meant the code behind it, not the reasoning.

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the error you have posted. Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. When I copy and paste your model and run `decoder.fit` on random data of the shapes you've provided, it runs as intended. `input` is a poor choice for a variable name for your data because input is a predefined function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This above mentioned code is not showing any error when I tried replicating it in Google colab using `TF 2.9` and `TF 2.8` and in `jupyter notebook` using `TF 2.9`.

Please check [this](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/2a60bb9d4c1f304ec58a41bf10366bad/73834600.ipynb) gist as a reference for the same. Let us know the tensorflow version and python version installed in your system for further understanding if the issue still persists.

**Note:** It is always a good practice to import keras and it's other libraries from tensorflow as below -

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```